# Share point Workflow 2010 Document Creation from Template File

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, workflow, document, designer

We have created a workflow on a List that creates a new document in a specific document library based on a template file.  We would like to add automation so that a user could choose the template file that they would like to use when "running" the workflow.

We have searched around and found many tutorials on document creation, but none where you selected the template you wanted to use.

Any help?

Comment: StackOverflow isn't appropriate for providing references to tutorials. You would find your question better answered if you focussed on the problem, what you have tried, and what error messages are seen.

Comment: For the amount of time it took you to write this you could have helped point someone in the correct direction.  I tend to appreciate people who help solve problems over enforcing policy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with Content type. You can link a template to a content type. So Create X content type on your list (X = number of your template file) and link template file to content type.

to sum up :

1. Enable content type on your document Lib
2. Create a Content type on your list
3. Upload and Link template file to your content type
4. When create new document, choose your content type to change the template file

Comment: Thanks, We will try this and report our finding back.